# Backbone save triggers 'get' request + urlRoot gets ignored

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I have the strangest issue ever.

I instantiate the most basic model:

```
define([
  'backbone'
], function(Backbone){

    //Role - permissions model 
    var Rp_model = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
        urlRoot: '/ingeb/api_v1/users/rolespermissions/'
    }); 

    return Rp_model; 

});
```

And I save the model like this:

```
Rolespermissions_controller.prototype.save_userpermission = function(resource_id, role_id, verb){ 
    var rp_model = new Rp_model({'resource_id': 1, 'role_id': 1, 'verb': 'get'}); 
    console.log(rp_model); 
    console.log(rp_model instanceof Backbone.Model); 
    console.log(rp_model.urlRoot); 
    rp_model.save(); 
};
```

The console.logs generate the following output:

[image]

It doesn't make any sense to me.
I'm saving the model, and it makes a 'GET' request to the backend.
Also, it's not clear to me why it ignores the URLRoot completely.

Comment: can you try to do : console.log(rp_model.url());

Comment: Thanks, but I found it. Almost can't believe that I lost two hours on this, while I only had to remove the last slash in the definition of the URLRoot:  urlRoot: '/ingeb/api_v1/users/rolespermissions',

Answer (score 0):

I had a trailing slash at the end of the urlRoot definition. 
It should be:

```
var Rp_model = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    urlRoot: '/ingeb/api_v1/users/rolespermissions', 
});
```